# Graph API Error "Authentication failed. No retry with popUp. Inner Exception: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties."

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am using Graph API in Canvas App in Power Apps. I am getting events from Shared Calendar and the request happens every 30 seconds. A few hours later this error appears:

GraphAPI.FutureEventsFromSharedCalendar failed: Authentication failed. No retry with popUp. Inner Exception: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties.

Comment: Looks like Power Apps issue: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Property-storage-exceeds/td-p/848243/page/2

Answer (score 0):

1. One may need to frequently check the  memory consumption of the
   canvas app. Most of the cases, the cause is the memory exceptions in
   the heap crash in  Memory exceptions in the heap that freezes the
   operation on certain devices.
2. If  client-heavy operations  happen, the objects in the heap will
   increase, resulting in exceeding memory limits.
3. One of the workaround maybe to profile app performance and
   memory.Developer tools for most browsers allow you to profile
   memory. It helps to  visualize heap size, documents etc .

Please check this document to [***Fix memory problems***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/memory-problems/) to workaround which explains the use Microsoft Edge and DevTools to find memory issues that affect page performance, including memory leaks, frequent garbage collections and memory bloat.
Try to find how much memory your page is  using with the Microsoft Edge Browser Task Manager.

[image]

Reference : [Tips and best practices to improve performance of canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/performance-tips)